# Using numpy shape output in logic

Tags: python, numpy, int, long-integer, shapes

I am using Python 2.7.5 on Windows 7. For some reason python doesn't like it when I use one of the dimensions of my numpy array to with a comparator in an if statement:

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,4])
# reshapes so that array has two dimensions
if len(np.shape(a)) == 1:
    a = np.reshape(a, (1, np.shape(a)))

b = np.shape(a)[0]

if b <= 3:
    print 'ok'
```

I create a 1D numpy array (in actuality 'a' is an input that may be 1D or 2D). Then I reshape this to form a 2D numpy array. I try to use the size of the newly created dimension as a comparator and I get an error: "TypeError: an integer is required"

I also tried "int(b)" to convert the long integer to a plain integer in the if statement and it gives the same error. If I do "type(b)" it gives me "type 'long'". I feel as though I've done this before without any problems, but I can't find any examples. Is it something with how I change the 1D array to a 2D array? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: which line throws the error?

Comment: `np.shape(a)` will be a tuple, so you'll end up with a tuple inside a tuple when you do `(1, np.shape(a))`

Comment: Sorry for not being more specific. The second if statement throws the error, "if b <=3:", but the posters below are correct that the error is actually in how I reshape a.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problematic line is `a = np.reshape(a, (1, np.shape(a)))`.

To add an axis to the front of `a` I'd suggest using:

```
a = a[np.newaxis, ...]

print a.shape # (1, 4)
```

or `None` does the same thing as `np.newaxis`.

Comment: This one works, as well as the answer given below... Thanks tom10 and Padraic Cunningham!

Answer (score 3):

You are creating a tuple with np.shape so you are passing `(1,(4,))` so the error has nothing to do with your if, it is what is happening inside the if , you would need to use  `np.shape(a)[0]` but I am not fully sure what you are trying t do:

```
 np.shape(a)[0]
```

Or simply `a.shape[0]`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to do the same thing as `np.atleast_2d`:

```
def atleast_2d(*arys):   # *arys handles multiple arrays
    res = []
    for ary in arys:
        ary = asanyarray(ary)
        if len(ary.shape) == 0 :
            result = ary.reshape(1, 1)
        elif len(ary.shape) == 1 :  # looks like your code!
            result = ary[newaxis,:]
        else :
            result = ary
        res.append(result)
    if len(res) == 1:
        return res[0]
    else:
        return res

In [955]: a=np.array([1,2,3,4])
In [956]: np.atleast_2d(a)
Out[956]: array([[1, 2, 3, 4]])
```

or it is a list:

```
In [961]: np.atleast_2d([1,2,3,4])
Out[961]: array([[1, 2, 3, 4]])
```

you can also test the `ndim` attribute: `a.ndim==1`