# Python: How can I force 1-element NumPy arrays to be two-dimensional?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have piece of code that slices a 2D NumPy array and returns the resulting (sub-)array. In some cases, the slicing only indexes one element, in which case the result is a one-element array:

```
>>> sub_array = orig_array[indices_h, indices_w]
>>> sub_array.shape
(1,)
```

How can I force this array to be two-dimensional in a general way? I.e.:

```
>>> sub_array.shape
(1,1)
```

I know that `sub_array.reshape(1,1)` works, but I would like to be able to apply it to `sub_array` generally without worrying about the number of elements in it. To put it in another way, I would like to compose a (light-weight) operation that converts a shape-(1,) array to a shape-(1,1) array, a shape-(2,2) array to a shape-(2,2) array etc. I can make a function:

```
def twodimensionalise(input_array):
     if input_array.shape == (1,):
         return input_array.reshape(1,1)
     else:
         return input_array
```

Is this the best I am going to get or does NumPy have something more 'native'?

**Addition:**

As pointed out in https://stackoverflow.com/a/31698471/865169, I was doing the indexing wrong. I really wanted to do:

```
sub_array = orig_array[indices_h][:, indices_w]
```

This does not work when there is only one entry in `indices_h`, but combining it with `np.atleast_2d` suggested in another answer, I arrive at:

```
sub_array = np.atleast_2d(orig_array[indices_h])[:, indices_w]
```

Comment: Your function is a simple version of `atleast_2d`, and just as 'native'.  Look at its code.

Comment: @hpaulj Yes, so I figured after I read http://stackoverflow.com/a/31698359/865169

Comment: full `atleast_2d` code is listed http://stackoverflow.com/a/31550687/901925

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It sounds like you might be looking for [`atleast_2d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.atleast_2d.html). This function returns a view of a 1D array as a 2D array:

```
>>> arr1 = np.array([1.7]) # shape (1,)
>>> np.atleast_2d(arr1)
array([[ 1.7]])
>>> _.shape
(1, 1)
```

Arrays that are already 2D (or have more dimensions) are unchanged:

```
>>> arr2 = np.arange(4).reshape(2,2) # shape (2, 2)
>>> np.atleast_2d(arr2)
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3]])
>>> _.shape
(2, 2)
```

Answer (score 5):

When defining a numpy array you can use the keyword argument `ndmin` to specify that you want at least two dimensions.
e.g.

```
arr = np.array(item_list, ndmin=2)
arr.shape
>>> (100, 1) # if item_list is 100 elements long etc
```

In the example in the question, just do

```
sub_array = np.array(orig_array[indices_h, indices_w], ndmin=2)
sub_array.shape
>>> (1,1)
```

This can be extended to higher dimensions too, unlike `np.atleast_2d()`.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you are indexing in the way you want to? In the case where `indices_h` and `indices_w` are broadcastable integer indexing arrays, the result will have the broadcasted shape of `indices_h` and `indices_w`. So if you want to make sure that the result is 2D, make the indices arrays 2D.

Otherwise, if you want all combinations of indices_h[i] and indices_w[j] (for all i, j), do e.g. a sequential indexing:

```
sub_array = orig_array[indices_h][:, indices_w]
```

Have a look at the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) for details about advanced indexing.

Comment: You're right. I am not indexing the way I want here. I see now that I should probably be indexing with a mesh grid.

Comment: And I see now that your suggested indexing is what I was thinking about doing with `np.meshgrid`.