# How can I always have numpy.ndarray.shape return a two valued tuple?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, shapes

I'm trying to get the values of (nRows, nCols) from a 2D Matrix but when it's a single row (i.e. x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])), x.shape will return (4,) and so my statement of (nRows, nCols) = x.shape returns "ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack"

Any suggestions on how I can make this statement more adaptable? It's for a function that is used in many programs and should work with both single row and multi-row matices. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could create a function that returns a tuple of rows and columns like this:

```
def rowsCols(a):
    if len(a.shape) > 1:
        rows = a.shape[0]
        cols = a.shape[1]
    else:
        rows = a.shape[0]
        cols = 0
    return (rows, cols)
```

where `a` is the array you input to the function. Here's an example of using the function:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([1,2,3])

y = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]])

def rowsCols(a):
    if len(a.shape) > 1:
        rows = a.shape[0]
        cols = a.shape[1]
    else:
        rows = a.shape[0]
        cols = 0
    return (rows, cols)

(nRows, nCols) = rowsCols(x)

print('rows {} and columns {}'.format(nRows, nCols))

(nRows, nCols) = rowsCols(y)

print('rows {} and columns {}'.format(nRows, nCols))
```

This prints `rows 3 and columns 0` then `rows 4 and columns 3`. Alternatively, you can use the `atleast_2d` function for a more concise approach:

```
(r, c) = np.atleast_2d(x).shape

print('rows {}, cols {}'.format(r, c))

(r, c) = np.atleast_2d(y).shape

print('rows {}, cols {}'.format(r, c))
```

Which prints `rows 1, cols 3` and `rows 4, cols 3`.

Answer (score 1):

If your function uses

```
 (nRows, nCols) = x.shape
```

it probably also indexes or iterates on `x` with the assumption that it has `nRows` rows, e.g.

```
 x[0,:]
 for row in x:
    # do something with the row
```

Common practice is to reshape `x` (as needed) so it has at least 1 row.  In other words, change the shape from `(n,)` to `(1,n)`.

```
 x = np.atleast_2d(x)
```

does this nicely.  Inside a function, such a change to `x` won't affect `x` outside it.  This way you can treat `x` as 2d through out your function, rather than constantly looking to see whether it is 1d v 2d.

[Python: How can I force 1-element NumPy arrays to be two-dimensional?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31698242/python-how-can-i-force-1-element-numpy-arrays-to-be-two-dimensional#comment51350833_31698242)

is one of many previous SO questions that asks about treating 1d arrays as 2d.